# Why is my camera orbit flying off in the negative z?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, orbital-mechanics

I lifted most of this code from a year-old unity thread. Whenever I run it, my camera goes running off in the negative z direction very quickly. I've been poking at the variables all day, but nothing is making it click for me.

The z changes by 5 units every frame, which is exactly what I have set for the camera distance. This seems like the key to understanding the issue. Part of my problem is that I only barely grasp moving objects around using transforms and Euler angles. Thank you for your time.

```
public GameObject cameraTarget = null;

public float cameraSpeedX = 120.0f; //x sensitivity
public float cameraSpeedY = 120.0f; //y sensitivity
public float cameraVelocityX = 0.0f;
public float cameraVelocityY = 0.0f;
public float cameraRotationX = 0.0f;
public float cameraRotationY = 0.0f;

public float cameraLimitMinY = -20f;
public float cameraLimitMaxY = 80f;

public float cameraDistance = 5.0f;
public float cameraDdistanceMin = 0.5f;
public float cameraDistanceMax = 15.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
    gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
    cameraRotationX = angles.x;
    cameraRotationY = angles.y;

    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if(GetComponent<Rigidbody>()){GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;}
    cameraTarget = gameObject;

}

void LateUpdate(){
    if (cameraTarget){
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)){
            cameraVelocityX += cameraSpeedX * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 0.02f;
            cameraVelocityY += cameraSpeedY * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 0.02f;
        }

        cameraRotationY += cameraVelocityX;
        cameraRotationX -= cameraVelocityY;

        cameraRotationX = ClampAngle(cameraRotationX, cameraLimitMinY, cameraLimitMaxY);

        //Quaternion fromRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.Euler(cameraRotationX, cameraRotationY, 0);
        Quaternion rotation = toRotation;

        Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -cameraDistance);
        Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + cameraTarget.transform.position;

        transform.rotation = rotation;
        transform.position = position;

        cameraVelocityX = Mathf.Lerp(cameraVelocityX, 0, Time.deltaTime * 2.0f);
        cameraVelocityY = Mathf.Lerp(cameraVelocityY, 0, Time.deltaTime * 2.0f);

        print ("POSITION:"+transform.position);
    }
}

public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max){
    if (angle < -360F)
        angle += 360F;
    if (angle > 360F)
        angle -= 360F;
    return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
}
```

Comment: You're sure you didn't set the cameraTarget to be the camera itself?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it... I might have.

Comment: haha. yeah. that would explain the behavior

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I thought that putting the camera script and the game object generation in the same object was a good idea. The camera transforms were being applied to itself, which caused the camera to endlessly try to get behind itself. Thank you mprivat for your insight.